# Appengine Python Bulk Export error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This seems to run for ~42,200 records then fails:

```
import datetime
import time

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
from google.appengine.api import datastore_types

class SearchRec(db.Model):
  WebSite = db.StringProperty()
  WebPage = db.StringProperty()
  DateStamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  IP = db.StringProperty()
  UserAgent = db.StringProperty()


class TrackerExporter(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'SearchRec',
                                    [('WebSite', str, None),
                                    ('WebPage', str, None),
                                    ('DateStamp', lambda x: str(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y').date()), None),
                                    ('IP', str, None)
                                    ])

exporters = [TrackerExporter]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bulkload.main(TrackerExporter)
```

**Error:**

```
File "tracker-export.py", line 89, in <lambda>
        ('DateStamp', lambda x: str(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    ), None),

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Did you change your model's definition at some point between a db.StringProperty and a db.DatetimeProperty at some point in the past?

Comment: I did, but I dumped all of the data (till the model vanished) so that shouldnt affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly that would be happening.  I'm not too familiar with the Bulk Exporting facilities of App Engine, but it sounds like the `DateStamp` field is being given to the bulk exporter as a string (which is what your converter expects) for the first 42200 records and then, for some reason, it is given as a real `datetime.datetime` object.

Anyway, here's a treatment for this particular symptom:

```
lambda x: str((x if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')).date())
```

That should do the right thing if given either a string or a `datetime.datetime` object.  This might be a case where you should give it a dedicated function instead of torturing a `lambda` like that.

Comment: Had to chuckle; torturing a lambda ;) ... I did have this in a function as per an article on another site but when that resulted in the same error I went back to this. One day google will stop making things hard work :)